# We will select 3 participants and each will receive a goodie bag of their choice, **subject to availability.**

Tags: phrase-usage, sentence-usage

> We will select 3 participants and each will receive a goodie bag of their choice, **subject to availability.**

If no other context is provided, does the sentence convey that there are more than 1 goodie bag for the participants to select from? They can choose the one they desire but subject to availability?

The use of *subject to availability* here confuses me. Does it mean they can choose the one they desire but whether they will receive the one they desired depends on the stock availability? Regardless, they will still receive a goodie bag each.

Or *subject to availability* here means they might not receive a goodie bag, it is subject to availability?

Comment: [that there is more than one]

Comment: Hi @Lambie Thanks. `They can choose the one they desire but subject to availability?` means they can choose the one they desire but whether they will receive the one they desired depends on the stock availability? I edited my post to add this question.

Answer (score 3):

It could mean either.  "Subject to availability" is a stock legal phrase meaning: "if we run out, you can't sue us". You see it added to all sort of offers.

Here it means that if there is only one goodie bag left, then you don't get a choice, and if there are no goodie bags left, then you don't get a bag.  We can assume that the person making the offer *intends* that there will be enough goodie bags that all three selected participants will get a free choice, but isn't able to promise this in a legal sense.

Comment: Thanks. Does adding brackets make it less ambiguous? `We will select 3 participants and each will receive a goodie bag of their choice(subject to availability)` conveys that they will receive the one they chose only if it is available?

Comment: Either way is OK and the meaning is the same.  You can use this without sounding like you are thinking about legal action, it just means "expect a chance that we'll run out".  James is correct in calling it a "legal phrase", however.